# Rails nested serializer not using methods to break out keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, active-model-serializers

I want to use a serializer within another serializer so I can add a key-value pair at the top level but seems like when I do, the lower level serializer isn't working anymore-

*My files:*

**ItemsController**

```
class ItemsController

  def index
    open_items = Items.
      select("distinct on (open_item_id) *").
      preload(:company, :project)

    total = open_items.count("id")

    render json: {
      total: total,
      items: paginate(open_items, per_page: 2), serializer: ItemsSerializer
    }, status: :ok
  end
end
```

**ItemsSerializer**

```
class ItemsSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attribute :total
  has_many :items, serializer: ItemSerializer
end
```

**ItemSerializer**

class ItemSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :id,
        :project,
        :company,

```
  def company
    {
      name: object.company.name,
      id: object.company.id
    }
  end

  def project
    {
      name: object.project.name,
      id: object.project.id
    }
  end

end
```

I want to get another key/value pair to my serializer output in the below so that I can get something like this:

```
{
    "total": 1,
    "items": [
        {
          "id": 42920375,
          "company": {
            "id": 123,
            "name": "CompanyName"
          },
          "project": {
            "id": 456,
            "name": "ProjectName"
          }
        }
    ]
}
```

But currently, I'm getting:

```
{
    "total": 1,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 42920375,
            "company_id": 5842,
            "project_id": 191741,
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is `ItemsSerializer` doesn't work the way you want it. It needs to correspond to an active model name. What you got is the result of ActiveRecord's own `to_json` method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use ItemsSerializer that way. It needs to correspond to a model.

Active-Model-serializer will automatically serialize each object in an association with its own serializer:

["In your controllers, when you use render :json for an array of objects, AMS will use ActiveModel::ArraySerializer (included in this project) as the base serializer, and the individual Serializer for the objects contained in that array."](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-9-stable)

So there's no need to reinvent the wheels. Just do this:

```
render json: paginate(open_items, per_page: 2), status: :ok
```

Then each item will be processed by `ItemSerializer`. I don't see a way to add `total` here though.